# SQL Server Unexpected Results from Data Type Change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I am working with acoustic data that shows decibel levels broken down between frequencies (1/3 octave bands). These values were imported from a flat text file and all have 1 decimal (e.g., 74.1 or -8.0).

I need to perform a series of calculations on the table in order to obtain other acoustic measures (calculated minute-level data by applying acoustic formulas to my given second-level data.) I am attempting to do this with a series of nested select statements. First, I needed to get the decibel values divided by 10. I did fine with that. Now I'd like to feed the generated fields output from this select statement into another that raises 10 to the power of my generated values.

So, if the 20000_Hz field had a value of 16.3, my generated table would have a value of 1.63 for that record, and I'd like to nest that into another select statement that generates 10^1.63 for that field and record.

To do this, I've been experimenting with the POWER() function. I tried POWER(10,my_generated_field) and got all zeros. I realized that the format of the base determines the format of the output, meaning that if I did something like POWER(10.0000000000000000000,my_generated_field) I'd start to see actual numbers like 0.0000000000032151321. Also, I tried altering my table to change the data type for decibel values to decimal(38,35) to see what effect this would have. I believe I initially set the data type as float using the flat file import tool.

To my surprise, numbers that were imported from the flat text file did not simply have more zeros tacked on the end, but had other numbers. For instance, a number like 46.8 now might read something like 46.8246546546843543210058 rather than 46.8000000000000000 as I'd expect.

So my two questions are:

1) Why did changing data types not create the results I expected, and where is SQL getting these other numbers?

2) How should I handle data types for my decibel values so that I don't loose accuracy when doing the 10^field_value thing?

I've spent some time reading about data types, the POWER() function, etc., but still don't feel like I'm going to understand this on my own.

Comment: I would not recommend decimal but float for these kind of math operations. There are many reasons in computing where floating point numbers are better for computations than fixed point ones. Your data shouldn't be huge, so try float(53).

Comment: Did you import as float, then convert to decimal? Or did you throw away the first import, and re-import as decimal?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thanks! Any advice on the POWER() function? When I do POWER(10,my_generated_field) I get all zeros in my result set. Increasing decimal places after the 10 increases the "resolution" of my output so that with POWER(10.000000,my_generated_field) might yield something like: .0000087. However, increasing past 38 decimals (limit for decimal data type) throws an error. So, even if I am using float(53) for my decibels, the POWER() output seems to be limited by the base as a decimal anyways. Is there a way to specify the base as a float data type? Thanks!!

Comment: @pmbAustin I imported as float and then used an alter table statement to change the data type of the field to decimal.

Comment: If you're going to use numeric/decimal, you should import it that way, to avoid any weird float rounding errors or conversion noise.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be easier for us to help you if we have your DDL, sample data and code.

Comment: @pmbAustin Thank you! This was the solution to my problem.

Comment: @HABO Thank you! I was struggling with this, and your link is extremely helpful.